# Getting complete PATH of uploaded file - PHP

Tags: php

I have a form(HTML, PHP) that lets the end user upload a file to update the database(MySQL) with the records in the uploaded file(specifically .csv). However, in the phpscript, I can only get the filename and not the complete path of the file specificed. fopen() fails due to this reason. Can anyone please let me know how I can work on finding the complete path?

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File to upload : <input type ="file" name = "UploadFileName"></p><br />
    <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Press THIS to upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
   .....
......
   $handle = fopen($_FILES["UploadFileName"]["name"], "r"); # fopen(test.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
?>
```

Comment: this is helpful good question.

Comment: old question, still, I think such comment is missing here: `$_FILES["UploadFileName"]["name"]` does not exist. `$_FILES["UploadFileName"]["tmp_name"]` does and `move_uploaded_file` is meant to move from tmp name to whatever location you wish.

Comment: however, sometimes you NEED the complete path of the uploaded file (client side), for example, some file formats use directory hierarchy - this will be available as of 8.1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`name` refers to the filename on the **client-side**. To get the filename (including the full path) on the **server-side**, you need to use `tmp_name`:

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES["UploadFileName"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$target='uploads/'.basename($_FILES['UploadFileName']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadFileName']['tmp_name'],$target)) {

     //Insert into your db

     $fp = fopen($target, "r");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote like this:

```
$filePath = realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
```

This gave me the full path to the uploaded file in PHP. If you find 0 bytes problem in file download, just modify this content-lenght line like this

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filePath));
```

Where $filePath should be absolute path to file not just file handle.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code,

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES["UploadFileName"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
```

Answer (score 1):

I use like this...

```
<?php
$NameOriginal = $_FILES["UploadFileName"]['name'];
$Typo_Image = $_FILES["UploadFileName"]['type'];
$name_Temp = $_FILES["UploadFileName"]['tmp_name']; 
?>
```