# How to get full filepath when uploading files in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, fopen, filepath, fgetcsv

I really want to know how am I gonna get the full filepath when I upload a file in PHP?

Here's my my problem...

I am importing a csv file in PHP. Uploading a file isn't a problem but the function used to import csv files which is fgetcsv() requires fopen. fopen is the one giving me a headache because it requires an exact filepath which means that the file should be in the same directory with the php file. What if the user gets a file from a different directory.

Here's my codes:

**`index.php`**:

```
<form action="csv_to_database.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
 <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**`csv_import.php`**:

```
<?php
 if ($_FILES['csv_file']['error'] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES['csv_file']['error'] . "<br />"; 
 }else{ 

  if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {

   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    for ($c=0; $c < count($data) ; $c++) {
     echo $data[$c] . " ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
   }
   fclose($handle);
  }
 }
?>
```

fopen here can only get the filename which is passed  by the variable `$_FILES['csv_file']['name']`. I was trying to get any functions to get the full filepath for $_FILES in the internet but  can't find any.

I am very new to web development so pls be patient. Pls answer as simple as possible... Pls help...

Comment: Please first ofall provide the Dirctory path where this .CSV file located and where your this coding file is located

Comment: If you do a print_r($_FILES) you'll see that there's a lot more information you can use. For instance $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'] which contains the full (temporary) path of your uploaded file. `fopen` can do stuff with this. See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @vindia I think $_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'] shows where to store temporarily the uploaded file in the server. WHat I am asking is the filepath of the source.

Comment: You don't get the filepath of the source. **Never**. Browsers filter that out for security/privacy reasons. @vindia was pointing out the functionality bug in your code. You cannot use the clients file path on the server anyway. That's two different filesystems, the same path is not going to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450713/getting-complete-path-of-uploaded-file-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `['name']` refers to the original filename on the users computer. That's no use to you, in particular because it might be empty. (Or it can contain fake values, causing a directory traversal exploit. So, just avoid it.)

You need to use the `['tmp_name']` which is a server-absolute path like `/tmp/upload85728` that can be used for `fopen()` or `move_uploaded_file()`.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully imported csv file and stored it in the mysql database.

Here are the the codes (actually its almost the same as my question with some slight changes with great effect):

**`index.php`**:

```
<form action="csv_import.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
 <input type="file" name="csv_file" />
 <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**`csv_import.php`**:

```
<?php
 if ($_FILES['csv_file']['error'] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES['csv_file']['error'] . "<br />"; 
 }else{ 
  if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {

   $dbconn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't connect to server!");
   mysql_select_db("csv_test") or die("Couldn't find database!");

   $ctr = 1; // used to exclude the CSV header

   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($ctr > 1) mysql_query("INSERT INTO ninja_exer (name, village, country) VALUES ('$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]')");
    else  $ctr++;
   }
   fclose($handle);
  }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a path into your config file or wherever you want to use and then that variable whatever you define, you can use in you project.

```
i.e: define('FILE_UPLOADED_PATH','folder1/folder2/so on');
```

so after the put this code your full filepath would be-

```
FILE_UPLOADED_PATH.$_FILES['csv_file']['name'];
```

you can use above code as example.

Thanks.

Comment: What if the user uploaded a csv file not from the file path I specified

Comment: no..no..you are not understand actually what i mean.. whenever the user upload file from your site that file will upload to your specify path only.so at the time you need to edit/show u can easily get that back...thats what i suggest..thanks.

Comment: user can upload files from anywhere in computer but the files after uploaded would be at the specific path only. so its make our task simple.