# Ajax - Use FormData() to send a full file path rather than just a name

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to use Ajax and the FormData() object to send a file (as a blob) and it's full path and name to the server.  I can do this with a simple file name ("Page1.htm") but if I send any sort of path it gets stripped out and just the base file name is left.  How can I send a whole path and file name?

Client-side Javasctipt:

```
var pageblob = new Blob([pagecontent)], {type: "text/html"});
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Page", pageblob, "/path/pagename.htm");
```

Server-sdie PHP:

```
echo $_FILES["Page"]["name"];
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450713/getting-complete-path-of-uploaded-file-php

Comment: you can't get/set the full path for security reasons, but you can use a 2nd "input" to ship that string to the server.

Comment: guest271314:
Looked at that thread but it still doesn't show any way of passing a path along with the file.

Comment: dandavis:
Thats what I can't seem to get working, no matter how I try I cannot seem to get a second parameter being passed along with the file.