# Get filepath from where file is being uploaded

Tags: php, html

I am currently using local web server(using XAMPP).

I am selecting file using input type=file. 
I want to get the filepath, like if test.txt is on desktop, I should get the path i.e. C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test.txt.

Is it possible? How?
Basically, what I want is client-side path not a server-side .tmp file path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5450754/4248328

Comment: @Anant tmp_name gives path of temp file being created after uploading file. It is not giving me the path from where file is grabbed.

Comment: @Vineet1982 I want the client-side path not the server-side. tmp_name returns me the temporary file path.

Comment: @doge007 That's impossible

Comment: If you could do that, you could start reading through someones files on his computer *without* any knowledge, doesn't seem so secure does it?

Comment: I was expecting this to be possible for my localserver...since it doesn't have any file permission restrictions. Well..disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **no**.

You are **not** able to view a file on the clients computer, as that is a huge *security* issue. Now, in order to get the file and move it, there is a *temporary* file and position created so you can check and potentionally save it. You can get that file through this code:

```
$_FILES["UploadFileName"]["tmp_name"]
```