# How do I get the full path of an image

Tags: php, image

[image]

I want the full path of a selected image to be displayed once *Choose File* button is clicked. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your `$_POST` handling, use the following:

```
$fullpath = $_FILES["Name_Of_The_Input_Field_For_The_File"]["tmp_name"];
```

See [Getting complete PATH of uploaded file - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450713/getting-complete-path-of-uploaded-file-php) for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a double POST, you can do something like this:

```js
function readURL(input) {

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

Remember, that just because you've selected a file to upload doesn't mean its been uploaded. The server still hasn't received the data, thus, doing this on the client side makes a little more sense from what i gather you want to do.

(stolen from: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded#answer-4459419))