# How can i get full path of uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, html

How can i get Full path of uploaded file in php. As i uploaded a xml file and clicked on submit button full path of uploaded file will be shown on screen.

**HTML**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
{
 $file = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
 $filename = pathinfo($file);
 $st_name = $filename['filename'];
 $dir= $filename['dirname']; //directory name
 echo $dir;
}
```

Here as i click on submit button output should be like this...

```
**D://new/folder/file.xml**
```

Comment: The temporary path under with the uploaded file was stored, can be found under the `tmp_name` key. But you need to _move_ it from there to a different location first of all, otherwise it will automatically get deleted when your script ends. Please go read https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php, it explains really all you need to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting complete PATH of uploaded file - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450713/getting-complete-path-of-uploaded-file-php)

Comment: no this is not a right way

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
$uploads_dir = 'D://new/folder';

$tmp_name = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

$name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$path = $uploads_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .  $name;

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path);

echo $path;
```